# Positioning rows according to column values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to give rows in a table positions according to a particular column values.

E.g: Inserting data from a table with student names and marks into another table that will give automatically insert student positions in another column according to their marks. It should be noted that two or more students with the same mark will share a position. i.e. If there 3 students who obtained 60, then they will all have the same position.
I have a table with student names and marks and I have to insert into a new table that will also have the positions column.

Please assist how I can achieve that in SQL.

Ok, let's say I have the following data in my table:

> StudentNo   StudentMark
>   6548    |    79
>   8762    |    60
>   6874    |    58
>   3876    |    70
>   3676    |    60

And I would like to insert into another table such that it looks like this:

> StudentNo |  StudentMark | Position
>   6548 |       79     |        1
>   3876 |       70     |         2
>   3676 |       60      |        3
>   8762 |       60      |        3
>   6874 |       58      |        4

Comment: By `position` do you mean `ranking`?

Comment: Could you give a some sample data and a sample desired result? Preferably with two equal rankings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a table layout or SQL statement you have now to help you better, but [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) document is probably the thing you need. If you need more help, update your question.

Example:

```
select name
, dense_rank() over (order by mark) position
from table
order
by position
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your statement should look like this:

```
insert into Rank_Students(
 UserName,
 Mark, 
 Rank
)
select
 s.UserName,
 s.Mark,
 rank() over (order by s.Mark asc) as Position
from Student
;
```

If you do not want rank, you should use Dense_Rank i think.